# most local size useable locally

Tags: c, local-variables

using GCC (windows 32, C only, default build options ).

what is the largest size of my local stack.. ?

for example:

```
void myfunc (void)
{
char is_this_too_big_for_a_local_var[64*1024*1024];

somefunc(is_this_too_big_for_a_local_var);
}
```

possibly from some traumatic experience during my early days of coding, I've
never attempted to ever use more than at most 16k local storage.. ( yes, habits
picked up during the days of 286's, 16bit computers)..

Anyway, is locating really large variables locally OK ? or is a few K still 
the upper limit ?

Answer (score 2):

Even if your system has a large stack, you should not get in a habit of using it. Code with large stack frames becomes problematic as soon as you want to use it in multi-threaded programs, because each thread's stack needs to be large enough to accommodate the largest possible stack usage, and the code creating the thread will want to use `pthread_attr_setstacksize` (or equivalent) to avoid spending more virtual address space and commit charge than necessary on each thread.

**Edit:** Here's an idea for a "portable" (to POSIX systems) way to ensure you have the space you want on your main thread's stack:

1. At the beginning of main, copy `argv` to newly allocated memory.
2. Then create a new thread with the desired stack size, and pass it the copy of `argv`. This will fail and report the error if the desired size is not available.
3. In the new thread, re-invoke `main` with the new `argv`, but with a global flag set to avoid repeating steps 1/2.
4. `pthread_exit` from the initial "main thread" and treat your new thread as the "main thread".